# Java Synchronized Threads not working as expected

Tags: java, multithreading

The following code does not work as I expect it to:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;

class Worker implements Runnable {

    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Started.");
        process();

    }
    private Random random = new Random();

    private Object lock1 = new Object();
    private Object lock2 = new Object();

    private static List<Integer> list1 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    private static List<Integer> list2 = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    public void stageOne() {

        synchronized (lock1) {

            try {
                Thread.sleep(1);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            list1.add(random.nextInt(100));
        }

    }

    public void stageTwo() {

        synchronized (lock2) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            list2.add(random.nextInt(100));
        }
    }

    public void process() {
        for(int i=0; i<1000; i++) {
            stageOne();
            stageTwo();
        }
    }
    public static void show() {
        System.out.println("List1: " + list1.size());
        System.out.println("List2: " + list2.size());
    }
}

public class JavaTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();

        Thread t1 = new Thread(new Worker());
        t1.start();
        Thread t2 = new Thread(new Worker());
        t2.start();

        try {
            t1.join();
            t2.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        System.out.println("Completed.");

        long end = System.currentTimeMillis();

        System.out.println("Time taken: " + (end - start));

        Worker.show();
    }

}
```

When I run this program, I expect `list1` and `list2` to contain 2000 items each and for the program to take approximately 2000 milliseconds. However, lots of times I get lists less than 2000 items, although it does finish around 2000 milliseconds. Sometimes I even get a `ArrayOutOfBounds` Exception

```
Started.
Started.
Exception in thread "Thread-1" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 163
    at java.util.ArrayList.add(ArrayList.java:459)
    at Worker.stageOne(JavaTest.java:34)
    at Worker.process(JavaTest.java:53)
    at Worker.run(JavaTest.java:14)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Completed.
Time taken: 2217
List1: 1081
List2: 1079
```

I expect that each the locks in `stageOne` and `stageTwo` should stop the threads from interfering with each other. But that does not seem to be the case. What is the problem with this code?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your lock objects are not static, so each thread is synchronizing on a different monitor. So the locks are not having any effect at all.